# EditText.getText.toString() is returning empty string

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-edittext, android-toast

I am trying to recover the text from `EditText` but when I `Toast` the string I am getting an empty string.

Here is the code:

```
view =inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
EditText id=view.findViewById(R.id.busID);
busId=id.getText().toString();
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(final View view) {
          Toast.makeText(getContext(),busId,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     }
});
```

Here is the screenshot

[image: ScreenShot]

Please help me out. I don't know why it is returning empty string

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are extracting the `String` from the `EditText` too early.

Change your code like this:

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(final View view) {
          busId=id.getText().toString();
          Toast.makeText(getContext(),busId,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     }
});
```

Comment: Nice answer but a little advice to the question asker I recommend using variable names that are meaningful so ```EditText id=view.findViewById(R.id.busID);``` to something like bus_edit_text or something. If it is a local variable it will be find but in large projects this could cause issues especially if it was declared as a global variable.